# OData 3 for Web API 2: Properties of type System.Object are not sent to the client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am using `OData` v3 for `Web API 2` and finding that properties of type `System.Object` are **NOT** returned to the client at all. Example entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public object MyObjectField { get; set; }
    //etc 
}
```

Other properties are all fine, but any property of type `System.Object` is completely ignored. Can I get the API to call `.ToString()` or something on it so that it will be sent to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it's because `OData for Web API` is expecting the properties must be representative of DB fields and thus, `object` is unacceptable. That may be the case for 99% of the time, but it's a nasty limitation to have in those cases when you really want to return a **type** which is derived from the entity set, but which is not the **type** of the **entity** in that set (example: a view model with extra properties).

Anyway, for now I just changed my property to `string` and it works fine. That will have to do for now.